Blender Shape Key + Driver to Unity
I am looking for some help exporting blendshape drivers to unity.
I am working on a piece of clothing that I am exporting to unity in FBX format in order to create a game mod. In blender, I made some shape keys that help the shoulder strap of the garment deform more realistically when the arm is raised sideways and forwards etc, and they activate according to the rotation of the arm bone as intended.. but after exporting to unity and building the mod, I can see that the blendshapes are built into the garment and they correctly apply deformations when i manually change their value, yet they do not activate as dictated by the driver (based on upper arm rotation). It seems like the driver is not porting over or failing to be triggered.
Here are my export settings in blender (in hopes that the issue lies here):

For extra context, I should mention that the game I am modding requires me to use the ancient 2018/4/11 unity, and i am using Blender4.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Drivers aren't exportable, they need to be baked into keyframes. This script should do the job. If not, please [edit] your question to better detail your situation, why not even share your file.
